# Position a Button on a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am new to Android development, I am trying move a button on the screen, but it wont allow me to put it in the place I want it to, in addition to that, all my text boxes shift when I moved this button.. can some one help me?

By the way, I am using RelativeLayout.

here is what i have done:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/TextView01"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="15dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_weight="0.09"
       android:text="Name"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/etSQLHotness"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/bSQLView"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:ems="10" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/TextView02"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
       android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
       android:text="Age" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/etSQLName"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/etSQLHotness"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
       android:ems="10" >

       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
       android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
       android:text="Hotness scale 1 - 10" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/bSQLUpdate"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etSQLHotness"
       android:text="Update SQlite Database" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/bSQLView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bSQLUpdate"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bSQLUpdate"
       android:text="View" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To be able to help you, we need to see what you have by posting relevant code and logcat output. In this case, your xml should do. Otherwise, we have no idea what attributes you have set or anything else that may be making it not work :)

Comment: show us what you have done

Comment: Are you trying to place the button by Drag and drop from the palette..?

Answer (score 0):

in relative layout all the views position is relative to each other, so after placing them if you will try to move one of the view, all other views dependent on that will change their position, so instead of using your mouse in graphical layout, change your Xml accordingly,

Comment: well i dont really want relative layout if that is the case, I tried linearLayout, but that caused my buttons to just lock up... is there any way where i can drag and drop buttons/textviews etc on to the xml freely and place then where I want to??

Comment: in android freely drag n drop will not work, but using layouts you can put all your controls where ever you want

Comment: why did android do it this way? why didnt they make it like visual basic where you can drag and drop things freely ?

Comment: Right?? That's what I'm saying!